# Persistent crashing since March 14th update?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I saw that there were many new levels available today and started building many of them (about 10 residential, and 3 each of food/service/retail/recreation.)  The screen then became somewhat odd - the menu button was missing at the bottom of the screen and the bottom status info about how many coins and bux remain wasn't there, rather just a transparent section.  Then the game crashed and I haven't been able to get it to start again- it crashes upon launch.  Over and over.  I tried the usual things (launch the game in airplane mode, kill the app and try again) numerous times without success.  This is under iOS 6.

Has anyone else had this problem and been able to resolve it?  It's presently unlaunchable and thus unplayable.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same experience today. Added new levels up to total of 136. Bought 4 levels with credits then the rest a 1 BUX a level. Now game crashes at just over a quarter of the way through the TDS Startup screen.

At one point, I got to activate the "online" backup from four hours previous. I then went through the whole level purchase thing again, played 20 more minutes and then on restart, game crashes YET AGAIN.

Have tried startup a with game centre off, Facebook logged on / not logged on. Airplane mode..Nothing works. We need to wait for updates from the developer.